# Get the IP and Computer Name

Tags: vb.net, hostname

I have this code:

```
localIp = Request.UserHostName
hostName = DetermineCompName(localIp)

Session.Add("localIp", localIp)
Session.Add("hostName", hostName)
```

As you can see, I put the 2 variables on a session so that I can use it when I want. Testing the app on 10 computers, I saw that on some of the computers it gets the Client IP and the Computer name, but on others it goes empty.

As in some computers it works, I don't understand what's wrong. Does anyone have the right method to do this?

Comment: for hostname of the machine i've used:
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")).HostName

assuming this is ASP ?


For IP i think - Dim h As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")).AddressList(0) ?

Answer (score 3):

To get the computer name you can simply do:

```
Dim hostName As String = Environment.MachineName
```

or:

```
Dim hostName As String = My.Computer.Name
```

For the IP it's a little bit trickier, I assume you want the ipV4, so you can try this:

```
Dim localIp As String
For Each address As System.Net.IPAddress In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName).AddressList
    If address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        localIp = address.ToString()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Please note that if you do just:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

then this will return the ipV6.